# Why should the "T" in "T-shirt" be capitalized?

Tags: spelling, orthography, capitalization

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/T-shirt) says that the "T" in "T-shirt" should be capitalized, with "t-shirt" an [alternative spelling](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/t-shirt#English). Why is an upper case "T" preferred?

Comment: ? because T-shirts don't have long necks and curly tails ?

Comment: I've argued with Wiktionay for years that it has no business declaring one spelling to be the alternative to another. They should use a heading that doesn't lend superiority to one form such as **Spellings** or **Other spellings**. Wiktionary entries vary as to how one word is given the "main" entry and others the "alternatives". Sometimes there's a Google Fight, sometimes it's first come first served, sometimes there's a small battle between who is right among British English and American English! **Do not trust these Wiktionary labels!**

Comment: Another piece of advice: Don't expect any dictionary to be prescriptive unless it's older than Webster's Third New World Dictionary. By this time all major English dictionaries published in Britain and USA had firmly chosen the path of descriptivism. That means they claim to describe how the language is used, and specifically do not tell people the correct way to use the language. For questions of usage you would do better to consult style guides, such as *Strunk and White*.

Comment: @hippietrail you're doing to comments what Mick Dundee does to knives! :) Anyway, I've opened up a question on how much I should trust Wiktionary at http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/1307/54

Comment: If I go too Mick Dundee I could risk ending up living as a tax exile in the US! (-;

Comment: @hippietrail Strunk & White? [*falls to the floor and writhes in anguish*]

Comment: @StoneyB: Hey I'm not a fan of Strunk & White but unlike dictionaries they do style themselves arbiters of "correct English".

Comment: @hippietrail  So do I; so, for that matter, do you, and everybody else who Answers here. But unlike White, I consult my audience. And, also unlike White, I follow my rules in my own practise.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a T-shirt because its shape reminds of a capital letter T, in the same way an A-frame's shape reminds of a capital letter A.

[image: A-frame]

While it is more correct to say the shape reminds of a capital letter T, than a lowercase t, *t-shirt* would be equally understood.

Answer (score 9):

I have done some online research tonight, and found out that while many other formerly proper nouns such as *Internet,* and *E-mail* have transformed into common nouns, the powers-that-be have mostly resisted a similar transformation of *T-shirt* because the capital letter *T* shows the approximate shape of the item of clothing.  Other words like this are *A-frame, C-clamp, I-beam, L-bracket, O-ring, S-curve, T-shirt, T-square, T-junction, T-bar, U-turn*, and *V-neck*.

I did not come up with this myself; I found this information in the answer and ensuing conversation at [this ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27506/why-the-new-york-times-no-longer-capitalizes-e-mail/48245#48245).

I hope this helps, and look forward to hearing what others have to say.

Comment: I can see why we wouldn't want to switch to _a-frame_ and _l-bracket_; however, _o-ring, s-curve, c-clamp,_ and _v-neck_ would all work fine – upper or lower case. I'm thinking that there might be some kind of convention other than retaining the resemblance between the object and the letter after which it's named.

Comment: @J.R. I wonder if it's common to capitalize a letter when you're talking about the letter itself. The capitalization (or lack thereof) of "F word" might prove or disprove this theory.

Comment: @Andrew: I'm trying to think of an object that resembles a lower-case letter, but [D-hooks](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/317o7zxWo3L._SL500_AA300_.jpg) look like upper-case D, [B-hooks](http://www.buybuybaby.com/assets/product_images/230/146929125910c.jpg) look like upper case B, and [G-strings](http://www.intimatescare.com/images/Sexy%20Lingerie/G-STRING-with-RHINESTONE-IN-SILVER.jpg) look like – well, I can't figure out _what_ letter a G-string looks like.  :^)

Comment: @J.R. The letter I (without the serifs).  And when you loop the end of the string around the tuner a couple of times it *almost* looks like lower case i.   ;-)

Comment: Don't confuse the concepts of proper nouns and capitalization. There is no 1:1 correspondence. Proper nouns are one major instance of capitalizing, but not the only one.

Comment: I thought of another one yesterday that normally uses lower-case: _f-stop_. (That's nothing definitive, but it makes me lean toward the theory that upper-case letters are used when there is resemblance to the character itself.)

Comment: @J.R.: The holes in a violin are called "f holes" [lowercase] because they are shaped like a lowercase "f".